# I would like to select one cell and highlight different cells in the same Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, highlight

I would like to know if it is possible to just click one cell and then different cells be automatically highlighted. For example, when I click B3 cell I would like to highlight cells: G3, L3, Q3, V3, AA3:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't need to change colour or anything, I just want to "see" them more easily.

Comment: any idea how in different way make it looks good ?

Comment: super! it is not what I was looking for but it will do the job! Many thanks pnuts!

Answer (score 1):

A hack (seemingly adequate according to OP) but options are limited.  Put:

```
=B3+G3+L3+Q3+V3+AA3
```

in a cell somewhere and double-click on that to pick out the locations of the components of the formula.